# C++ Conditional Statement (Correct Syntax)

Tags: java, c++, arduino

Is `if (a && b)` the same as `if ( (a) && (b) )`? If not, what's the difference between the two?

Comment: They could be different in a macro.

Comment: Deleting `"quick response highly appreciated"`. Your question is no more important than any other question on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general case they are not the same.

Let's assume that a and b are some expressions. For example a is expression `x += z` and `b` is a single variable `y`

Now consider the following code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
   int x = -1;
   int y = 1;
   int z = 2;

   // x += z corresponds to a
   // y corresponds to b

   if ( x += z && y ) std::cout << "( x += z && y ) is equal to true" << std::endl;
   else std::cout << "( x += z && y ) is equal to false" << std::endl;

   x = -1;

   if ( ( x += z  ) && ( y ) ) std::cout << "( ( x += z  ) && ( y ) ) is equal to true" << std::endl;
   else std::cout << "( ( x += z  ) && ( y ) ) is equal to false" << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
( x += z && y ) is equal to false
( ( x += z  ) && ( y ) ) is equal to true
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, both are the same.

Comment: @DesertIvy: of course it provides an answer. The question is "are they the same?", this answer is "they are the same".